# How to identify whether web service is REST or SOAP?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, spring-mvc, soap

I am learning spring MVC and have wrote following code. I read some articles about SOAP and REST but in the beginner level controller code I have written I am not able to distinguish whether SOAP or REST is used. My controller code is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.model.Customer;

@Controller
public class SelectController {




    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String display(){

        System.out.println("Inside controller");
        return "demo";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String indexpage(HttpServletRequest req, Model m){

        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String pass = req.getParameter("pass");

        String random = req.getParameter("abc");


        System.out.println("Index page"+name+pass+random);

        Customer cust = new Customer();

        cust.setUsername(name);
        cust.setPassword(pass);

        System.out.println("Index page"+name+pass);

        m.addAttribute("customer", cust);
        return "hello";
    }
```

Comment: It's not a webservice at all. That's just a normal controller without any RESTfulness and there's no trace of SOAP either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controller that you have written is

> neither REST nor SOAP.

**Its a MVC Controller**. 
In your case, your returning "hello" string at the end of controller method, which in-turn gets translated/mapped to a page(hello.jsp or hello.html based on the configuration) and returns the same. So, at the end, what you get is Page rendered in a beautiful way with all the necessary Stylings and scripts applied.

In contrast, REST and SOAP doesn't work in that way. Its main purpose is for transferring the data alone(Yet you can send HTML page also)

Writing a REST Service is almost similar to what you have currently and is fairly easy. If you use Springboot then all you have to do is just replace the `@Controller` annotation with `@RestController` and return Customer object directly. In REST Controller you wont have `HttpServletRequest` & `Model` arguments.

But writing a SOAP service is another topic which may seem entirely different.
There are tons of examples and tutorials scattered around the web, which you can find easily on these topics.

**References :**

[Controller vs RestController in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-controller-vs-restcontroller)

[Difference between Controller & RestController in Spring](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2017/08/difference-restcontroller-controller-annotation-spring-mvc-rest.html)

[SOAP vs REST](https://raygun.com/blog/soap-vs-rest-vs-json/)

Hope this gives some high level idea of what those three are.